# Why wont MPI finalize gracefully?

Tags: linux, mpi

Whenever I try to  finalize my mpi program, i get errors similar to the following.

```
[mpiexec] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (./tools/demux/demux_poll.c:70): assert (!(pollfds[i].revents & ~POLLIN & ~POLLOUT & ~POLLHUP)) failed
[mpiexec] main (./pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:221): demux engine error waiting for event
[mpiexec] HYDT_bscu_wait_for_completion (./tools/bootstrap/utils/bscu_wait.c:99): one of the processes terminated badly; aborting
[mpiexec] HYDT_bsci_wait_for_completion (./tools/bootstrap/src/bsci_wait.c:18): bootstrap device returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (./pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:352): bootstrap server returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec] main (./ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:294): process manager error waiting for completion
```

Sometimes, it gets a glibc "double free or corruption" error instead. Each process is single-threaded, and each process is for sure calling MPI_Finalize(). Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure, that every process is calling MPI_Finalize?

Could you dump the return codes of the MPI_Finalize function? Like
int ret_code = MPI_Finalize();
if(0 == my_rank) fprintf(stderr, "Process, return_code");
fprintf(stderr, "%i, %i", my_rank, )

and then 1) count the number of lines -- should be equal to number of MPI processes, otherwise some of the processes did not actually called MPI_Finalize; 2) check if all error codes are similar.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The problem is when the last process calls it. I dump the error codes and print them. All processes return 0, except the process with 0 rank which doesn't return anything. It just crashes at finalize with this error message. I can even put the 0th process to sleep for 5 seconds and see that the other processes are also holding at finalize, but then crashes as soon as process 0 calls finalize.

Comment: Now, I'm not sure whats going on because as I trying to find out the error (mainly by adding a bunch of print statements around finalize), it stopped doing it. Now I can't replicate the error anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a small test programm that should exit without any errors. Please try to run it. If it exits gracefully, then the problem is with your code.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int my_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    int finalize_retcode = MPI_Finalize();
    if(0 == my_rank) fprintf(stderr, "Process, return_code\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "%i, %i\n", my_rank, finalize_retcode);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It does run, and I am sure the problem is with my code. I'm just not sure where to begin looking. I guess my question is that, assuming I'm calling MPI_Init correctly (exactly as you have done), and MPI_Finalize() for every process, what kind of code in between could possibly cause this crash?

Comment: I am not aware of what kind of code could cause such a problem... If I'd be you I would do a binary search for an error: delete the half of the program, then if the error persists, delete another etc. I'd also try to reduce my code to something similar to the program above and thus double check, that it works, i.e. that the basic things do work. Check if you are using same MPI communicators, when you call MPI_Finalize, perhaps your process #0 has changed it. Check if you are not calling some of the MPI setup routines twice -- perhaps it matters, although I am not sure.

Comment: Heap corruption errors often do not show up until later in your program, and in my experience, MPI_Finalize() will uncover any memory errors you may have caused by writing off the end of an array, using new/free(), or malloc()/delete (in C++), etc... Plenty of tools  could help you uncover these sorts of errors (e.g. valgrind, http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.mpiwrap), and I think your instinct is correct - that this isn't an MPI problem. Most likely, it's an error happening somewhere between the last time you free() or delete memory, and your call to MPI_Finalize().

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a similar problem.

```
    MPI_Request* req = (MPI_Request*) malloc(sizeof(MPI_Request)*2*numThings*numItems);
    int count;
    for( item in items ) {
       count = 0;
       for( thing in things ) {
          MPI_Irecv(<sendBufF>, 1, MPI_INT, <src>, <tag>, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[count++]);
          MPI_Isend(<recvBufF>, 1, MPI_INT, <dest>, <tag>, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[count++]);
       }
    } 

    MPI_Status* stat = (MPI_Status*) malloc(sizeof(MPI_Status)*2*numThings*numItems);
    MPI_Waitall(count, req, stat);
```

The call to `MPI_Waitall(...)` is made with a value of `count` that is less then the number of Isend and recv's performed; which results in messages not being received.  Moving `count=0` outside the for loops resolved the `MPI_Finalize(...)` error.

Comment: thanks! I had a test case that was randomly crashing on MPI_Finalize and this was the exact issue. I had a typo in the # of messages param to MPI_Waitall.