# mpi_finalize hang due to pending message, can I finish program without calling mpi_finalize

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have a very long FORTRAN+MPI codes that hang at mpi_finalize() step. It probably due to pending message. I can get the output expected even I "ctrl-c" abort that hanged program.

The question here is: Can I remove the mpi_finalize() from my code, will there be any potential problems? It seems that by removing mpi_finalize() the output doesn't differ, and the program can quit without error.

The compiler I use is "ifort version 13.1.1".

Thanks.

-Kai

Comment: With most MPI implementations, if even a single process exists without calling `MPI_FINALIZE`, the whole MPI job would get aborted.

Comment: Try to add a `MPI_Barrier();` or `printf("rank %d\n",rank);` just before the `MPI_Finalize();` : this will tell you who is waitting. Leaving pending messages means potential troubles in the future...

Comment: @francis I put the MPI_Barrier() before MPI_Finalize(), and print the ranks who pass that barrier. It turns out that, all ranks can successfully execute the MPI_Barrier(). But after that, the program stuck in the MPI_Finalize().

Comment: @HristoIliev May I say that, if there's MPI_Barrier() before MPI_Finalize(), and the calculation output has been saved before all proc reached the barrier, I should have the "right" answers from my program, no matter the MPI_Finalize() can be executed or not?

Comment: If job crashes are considered part of the right answer - then yes. Otherwise you should run your program in a parallel debugger and see if there are any pending operations at the time when `MPI_FINALIZE` is called. A forgotten `MPI_ISEND` or `MPI_IRECV` that is never waited on is a prime candidate for such an operation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418716/why-wont-mpi-finalize-gracefully

Comment: A good way of achieving this behavior is allocating an array for the messages used in MPI_ISend and MPI_IRecv that is smaller than the number of messages open that are being waited for in the MPI_Waitall

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using non-blocking sends and receives that write out of bounds in the array that collects the information that is used in the MPI_Waitall function.