# Problem with MPI_Finalize at the end of a code

Tags: fortran, mpi, finalize

I have a Fortran 90 code which uses the MPI library.  At the end of the code, I have the following statements to finish the program:

```
call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
write(6,*) ierr
stop
```

The code to MPI_Finalize seems to result in an endless loop and the statements which write the `ierr` flag(which should be zero for each process), do not produce output and the program keeps on running endlessly.  The root process writes a file to disk and this is OK before MPI_Finalize is called.  What could be the cause of this problem which, by the way, only happens occasionally with our codes ? There is a thread with a similar issue posted on this forum before.

Comment: "There is a thread with a similar issue posted on this forum before." please give the reference to that thread. Also create a small complete program that shows the problem and indicate which how many processes you start the program.

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you remove `write(6,*) ierr`? The MPI standard recommends not doing anything between `MPI_Finalize` and the end of the program.

Comment: Here is the link to the other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913955/mpi-finalize-hang-due-to-pending-message-can-i-finish-program-without-calling-m?rq=1

Comment: The main program is big.  I will remove the statements after the MPI_Finalize statement.  The original code had no statements after MPI_Finalize but still this problem.  Maybe I can post a part of it to show you the contect ?

Comment: As the other thread says you may have outstanding non-blocking communications or out of array bounds memory accesses within MPI routines. Have you checked these possibilities? At the very least have you compiled with all debugging flags on and see if your program runs?

Comment: The program was compiled with several compiler options to trap errors but none are found. I tried introducing a Barrier statement but the blocking still happened. Finally, removing all barrier statements and MPI_Finalize at the end of the code results in successful completion.  So I think a problem with memory access is somewhere hidden, but I don't have a means to track it down.  In any case the practical issue of removing the blocking is solved.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point here but could it be as simple as not all of your MPI processes actually reaching the MPI_Finalize() statement? That would cause all of the other processes to block in the finalize as they will be waiting for the other process to arrive. Rather than writing to stdout, you could get each process to touch a file containing the rank in the name ("out.0", "out.1", ...) just before finalize which would give you a definitive answer as to how many processes are getting there ...